# Dashed lines only for covered boundaries with TQFT

Tags: tikz-pgf, tqft

I'm using [Andrew Stacey's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) wonderful [TQFT package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tqft) to create pictures of cobordisms. But I'm having trouble with the boundaries:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,tqft/reverse pair of pants,boundary lower style={draw,dashed}] (A) {};
        \node[label={below:should be solid}] at (A.outgoing boundary 1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My drawing convention for cobordisms is that the boundaries that are covered by the cobordism are dashed, and all that are visible should be solid. The above is how far I came - nearly all circles come out correctly, but the bottom circle should be completely solid. Is there a key for only styling the outgoing lower boundary?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of TikZ (3.0), by the way?  If so, I've rewritten the TQFT code to make use of the `pic` syntax that has now been introduced and with the rewrite I've added more styling options such as would fix this.  It's ready for testing from http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files (run `tex` on `tqft-pic.dtx` and look at `tqft-pic_test.tex` for examples) but I need to test it and rewrite the documentation before unleashing it on CTAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to work around this issue by drawing an additional boundary circle over the pair of pants (Thanks to Andrew Stacey to point this out):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,tqft/reverse pair of pants,boundary lower style={draw,dashed}] (A) {};
        \node[tqft boundary circle,draw] at (A.outgoing boundary 1) {};
        \node[label={below:should be solid}] at (A.outgoing boundary 1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class for examples.

Comment: @egreg, why not? What shall I use instead?

Comment: It's better to use `article` or `standalone`; the `minimal` class doesn't define font changing commands such as `\small`, for instance. See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114)

Comment: I don't have standalone installed, surprisingly.

Comment: There's a node shape `tqft boundary circle` which you can use rather than the `cap`.  Your middle node would be `\node[tqft boundary circle,draw] at (A.outgoing boundary 1) {};`.  The ability to style incoming and outgoing boundary components differently is on the TODO list for this package.

Answer (score 4):

You define a global setting for `lower boundary` via `every ...` key. So you need to overwrite it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every tqft/.style={draw,boundary lower style={draw,dashed}}]% DASHED!!!
        \node[tqft/pair of pants] (A) {};
        \node[tqft/reverse pair of pants,anchor=incoming boundary 1,
                    boundary lower style={draw,solid}% SOLID AGAIN HERE !!
                    ] (B) at (A.outgoing boundary 1) {};
        \node[label={below:should be solid}] at (B.outgoing boundary 1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not what I mean. Only the outgoing boundary of the lower, reverse pants should be solid.

Comment: @Turion Oops didn't even notice that. I'll check again.

Comment: I simplified the example so it's clearer what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Turion I found where the problem is and it is not possible to distinguish incoming and outgoing lower styles. If you want I can paste the problematic part but it's gonna be messy. Better I delete the answer and we call Andrew Stacey for a patch, what do you say?

Comment: Yes, calling Andrew Stacey is a good idea. But I would be sorry to see your answer deleted. I think I'll post a workaround instead so that your answer can stay as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have (on 7th April 2014) uploaded a new version of the `tqft` package to CTAN.  Once it propagates throughout the system, the following will achieve the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167836/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic[
  draw,
  tqft/reverse pair of pants,
  every lower boundary component/.style={draw},
  every incoming lower boundary component/.style={dashed},
  every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={solid},
  name=A
];
        \node[label={below:is solid}] at (A-outgoing boundary 1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This revision (which required TikZ3.0 or later) introduces far more styling possibilities.  In essence, any segment of the cobordism paths can be separately styled.

[image: TQFT with separate styling]